# Will the money I owe that I am going to payback to my sibling be taxed?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I recently completed my masters in the US, and started a job which pays decent. During my masters, my brother who works in the US paid for most of my tuition fee which is around 40000. I am planning to payback this amount to him though he never asked for it.

So my question is, when my brother gets this money will this be taxed for him? And I am planning to pay a bit more(May be 10000 extra) than what he has paid for the tuition as interest. is it a good idea? Finally, is it suggested to pay this money as installments or a lump sum?

Thanks in advance for valuable suggestions.

Comment: I presume those were actual gifts to you (no loan agreement, official or otherwise) over time. You can certainly pay him back, with the cleanest being payments of $17000 or less per year which fall under the current IRS gift limits so have no impact on estate taxes. (Gifts of any size are not subject to income tax.)

Comment: @JonCuster when you say gifts of any size are not subject to income tax, but the 17000 is the cleanest amount, can I still choose to pay over 17000 but need to do some other work along with it?

Comment: https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/frequently-asked-questions-on-gift-taxes is the starting point on IRS Gift Taxes

Answer (score 2):

Generally this would be subject to the [US Gift Tax](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/frequently-asked-questions-on-gift-taxes). However, there's an annual exemption of $17K per person per year, so you can give gifts to any person valued up to $17K per year (each) without worrying about the gift tax. To be on the safe side in terms of taxes (and in terms of your own financial stability), it may be better to give this money to your brother spread over 3 years instead of a lump sum.

Even if you give it in a lump sum, there's a very sizeable lifetime exemption that you will use to not pay any actual tax, but you'll need to file the tax forms ([form 709](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-709)) to report and claim it.

If there's any mention of your brother paying for your tuition as a loan documented anywhere (in your emails or something), then you can just claim it as a loan repayment. From your question it doesn't sound like there is though. That would make the extra $10K interest taxable income to your brother.

Comment: Because this sounds confusing: It’s 17,000 a year without filling out any forms or reporting anything, just hand over the cash. It’s several million in your lifetime, but you’ll have to fill in forms, inland revenue might want to know where the money came from and so on.

Comment: So $50,000 you’d just spread over three years, unless your sibling needs the money right now, say to buy a house. Then you have to fill out forms.